# jquery toggle open all div on one click

Tags: jquery, toggle

Please take a look at below codes, for whatever reason I am unable to open one div only when I click on the edit link, it opens all divs when I click the edit link.  This is what I have:

```
( function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $('.slickbox').hide();           
        // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.slickbox').toggle(400);
        return false;
        });
    });
} ) ( jQuery );
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<li id="list_47">
<div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="title id="bannerid59"><img src="banner_45_10.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="action"><a href="#" class=".slick-toggle">Edit</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-right">
        <span class="small">Sort Order: 2</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slickbox">blah blah box 1</div>
</li>

<li id="list_48">
<div>
    <div id="row">
        <div class="title id="bannerid60"><img src="banner_45_11.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="action"><a href="#" class=".slick-toggle">Edit</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row-right">
        <span class="small">Sort Order: 2</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slickbox">blah blah box 2</div>
</li>
```

I have looked through other examples or solutions with no luck (such as replacing $('.slickbox').toggle(400); with $(this).next(".slickbox").slideToggle(400);)

Any pointer is greatly appreciated.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slickbox').hide();           
    $('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.slickbox', $(this).parents("li")).toggle(400);
    return false;
    });
  });
}) ( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like `$(this).closest('.slickbox').toggle(400);`

the reason is that you have two div's with a class of slickbox and the jquery you have is just opening all of them.  you need to tell it to only open the one you want.

Comment: I replaced what you suggested and got no action when i clicked on the edit link...

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
$("div[slickbox]").toggle()
```

Haven't tried it, but I have done it to bind events and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could call one of the divs slickbox1 and the other slickbox2